# Creating Event Listeners for individual DIVS that have not been made yet, and how to trigger the individual command?

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

I am trying to create clickable divs that will set a variable once they are clicked.

For example,

If my program had to do with playing with balls.

When a user inputs a name, and what kind of ball they want (lets say name= Johnny and Ball=BasketBall) and then clicks "Create a Ball", My program will create a div called "Ball0". The "Ball0" div will display Johnny's name. When a user Clicks on his name it will say "Johnny has a BasketBall.

Here is how I am trying to do this code

```
var ballRefrence = -1;

function createBall() {
    ballRefrence +=1;
    var myElement = document.createElement('div');
    myElement.id = 'individualBall'+ballRefrence;
    ballArea.appendChild(myElement);//ball area is where I want to list the divs
    myElement.style.width = "550px";
    myElement.innerHTML= userName+" has bought a ball!";

    createEventListner();
}


function createEventListner() {
    var iBall = document.getElementById("individualBall"+ballRefrence);
    iball.addEventListener("click",showBall,false);
}


function playCaption() {
    //I am not sure how to pull the individual up here. 
    //Since I am using the "BallRefrence"variable
    //it will always be the last person clicked..
    //(Basically I cannot say 
    //alert.(ballRefrence);
}
```

I guess what I am trying to say is this, 
I have my "BallRefrence" that goes up by 1 each time.
I store all the items in an array. (so first person will go to index 0, second will go to index 1...ect)
I am having problems refrencing the element, because I am not sure how to pull the corrisponding numbe from the div.

Example:
After 3 clicks of "create ball" my html will look something like this.

```
    <div id = "individualBall0></div>
    <div id = "individualBall1></div>
    <div id = "individualBall2></div>
```

Since each individual div will match up to the element in the array I want, How will tell my program 
"When you click individualBall0, I want ball[0].."
or
"when you click indivdualBall2, I want ball[2]"

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: And, what exactly is your question?  `createBall()` looks like it should insert a new `div` and then `createEventListner()` should hook up an event handler for the newly created element (though there are much cleaner ways to write the code).

Comment: @Bergi - that was my thought when reading the title, but the OP's code is creating a new element and then assigning an event listener to it so I don't think this is an issue that needs delegated event handling (though it could be used here).

Comment: @Bergi: Definitely agree on the closure suggestion, but I'm not sure if the question is clear enough to know if the suggested duplicate (or close vote) is relevant.

Comment: @jfriend00: Beat me to the edit by two seconds!  :-)

Comment: Yeah, probably the title is misleading. @Daniel: Try to make a create-listener function that takes arguments, like `makeEventListener(myElement, userName)` - don't try to rely on a global variable.

Comment: Or use `this` in the event handler to refer to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: Or put a single listener on the *ballArea* element that handles clicks based on the event target.

Comment: Voting to reopen (my first time!) as neither the tags for this question nor the code provides mention jQuery.  The supplied duplicate only mentions jQuery solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that doesn't really follow your updated requirements (but I believe does something simpler) is on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/pHLu5/)**.  This stores the username and ball type in a local closure related to the event listener for that `DIV`.  The code is fairly simple, and it removes some clutter from the global namespace, revealing only `createBall`:

```
var createBall = (function() {
    var ballReference = -1;
    var ballArea = document.getElementById('ballArea');
    var showBall = function(userName, ballType) {
        return function(event) {
            alert(userName + ' has a ' + ballType);    
        };
    };
    return function() {
        ++ballReference;
        var userName = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var ballType = document.getElementById('ball').value;
        var myElement = document.createElement('div');
        myElement.id = 'individualBall'+ballReference;
        ballArea.appendChild(myElement);
        myElement.innerHTML= userName+" has bought a ball!";
        myElement.addEventListener("click",showBall(userName, ballType),false);
    };
}());
```

---

To perform your updated requirements, it should be pretty easy.  Your event handler will run in the context of your element, so something like this:

```
this.id.substring('individualBall'.length) //=> '0', '1', etc
```

should return a string representing the index of the div.  You can use that directly for indexing various arrays, or, if that makes you squeamish, turn it into an integer with `parseInt`, the `Number` constructor, or the unary `+` operator.

---

But note that the suggestions from Bergi, jfriend00, and RobG are all good.  There are many good ways of going about this.